# Setting constraints to UIScrollView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Need some help to set constraints to UIScrollView.

I tried to follow the instructions here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html (Mixed approach).

Setting 4 sided constraints to UIScrollView.
Then set 4 sided constraints to the buttonContainer.

This the result:

[image]

However xcode is giving this error message:

[image]

If I try xcode's recommendation, either the scrollview will not scroll, or it doesn't display at all.

Any idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The messages you are getting tell you what to do. The scroll view sets its content size and becomes scrollable through the constraints pinning its subview(s) to the scroll view itself. Those constraints must therefore provide sufficient information. You have not provided enough internal constraints to describe the height and width of the scrollable area (the content size).

In other words, think of the constraints as sizing the buttonContainer *from the inside out*. That is what you have neglected to do. You can solve this, for instance, simply by giving the buttonContainer an absolute width constraint and an absolute height constraint. And those values need to be *bigger* than the size of the scroll view itself if the content is to be scrollable.

Comment: The OP is trying to use Apple's mixed approach from the technical note. Is this even possible using Storyboard?

Comment: @bilobatum No, because you cannot set the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property of a view to NO if that view is already within a storyboard or nib with auto layout turned on. That is why in Apple's mixed approach the content view is created _in code_. However, the OP can do the "pure auto layout" approach, no problem, _entirely within the storyboard_.

Comment: By the way, it might help to look at my [downloadable example projects](https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples) (from my book) to see how to configure a scroll view entirely in the storyboard using auto layout. The ones you want to look at are currently called *bk2ch07p367scrollViewInNibAutolayout* and *bk2ch07p367scrollViewInNibAutolayout2*. Observe, when running them, that they scroll correctly even though the app has essentially no code; look at the constraints to see how that's configured (by two different strategies).

Comment: @matt Thanks I was able to fix it by adding width and height constraints to the `buttonContainer` instead of pinning it to the scrollview. However, in iOS 6.1.3, the buttons at the start of the content is clipped off when I pop viewcontrollers whose buttons appear towards the right of the container. Its fine in iOS 7 though. Any idea?

Comment: That would be a whole different question.

Comment: Yup. Was told that was a bug in iOS 6. Had to set `[_scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero];` to overcome it.