# Xcode embed all direct in scrollview without content view

Tags: ios, scrollview

I'm using Xcode 6.4 and I'm struggling with a large page with a bunch of various labels and text fields etc., that has to be scrollable. I looked at various tutorials some of which are obviously outdated and I had all my elements at first in a view that is inside of a scroll view. But that was a big pain with getting all the elements aligned properly using Auto Layout, in addition to not getting it to scroll either.

Now I see one person recommend using the following directly on the elements, without having a content view at all just a scroll view:

> Editor  -> Embed In -> Scroll View

I like it for the fact that nothing seems out of proportion, all the elements are shown on the iPhone exactly as I have it on the Storyboard without having to set any constraints, however I'm not able to get it to scroll.

This is my class

`class ResNotFoundViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate`

and I also try to set the height of the scrollview in the code as so:

`@IBOutlet weak var scrollviewoutlet: UIScrollView!`

and then this in the viewDidLoad as so:

`scrollviewoutlet.contentSize = CGSizeMake(375, 840)`

[image].

But I'm not able to get it to scroll at all, it will stay exactly like it opens up with From: Label being the last visible elements.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you're doing sounds right. Try this: implement `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to log `scrollviewoutlet.contentSize` and let's see if it really is getting the tall content size you are expecting. Oh, also log `scrollviewoutlet.bounds`. That's important, because if you've made a mistake on either the size of the content size or the size of the scroll view itself, it won't scroll.

Comment: Thanks . I actually want the hight to be 809. So I set it both in the storyboard as a constraint and in the code as shown before as well. After the viewDidLoad closure I put:
`override func viewDidLayoutSubviews () {
println("Now The contentSize is \(scrollviewoutlet.contentSize)")
        println("Now The bounds are \(scrollviewoutlet.bounds)")}`

and I get :

`Now The contentSize is (375.0, 809.0)
Now The bounds are (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 809.0)
Now The contentSize is (375.0, 809.0)
Now The bounds are (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 809.0)`

Interesting that it's echoing twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've located the problem, thanks to your logging. (Don't worry about the double call - how many times and when `viewDidLayoutSubviews` gets called is uninteresting.)

The problem is that you've set the scroll view *itself* to be taller than the window. In particular, it is 375x809. But so is its `contentSize`. Thus there is nothing to scroll. A scroll view can only scroll if its `contentSize` is *bigger* (in one or two dimensions) than the scroll view. (Moreover, a scroll view bigger than the screen is usually somewhat pointless, since there will be parts of its content that the user will never see - even scrolled all the way, that content will be offscreen.)

So, fix the size of the scroll view *itself* and you'll be fine. The best way is to assign it constraints that pin its boundaries to its superview, since the superview will have different sizes on different devices.

Comment: "But that was a big pain with getting all the elements aligned properly using Auto Layout, in addition to not getting it to scroll either." I would just like to point out that you really should learn to do this. It was a only "a big pain" because you're thrashing. It's actually very easy.

Comment: I fixed it a few days ago per your suggestion & everything came out fine. The size of the scroll view itself is determined by constraining to its superview. The errors were gone & scrolling worked as intended. I marked your answer as useful & correct & thanks again for that. However, in the interim I upgraded to Swift 2 & I now get the following yellow warning without making any changes: warning: Ambiguous Layout: Scrollable content size is ambiguous for "Scrollviewoutlet". Which I don't really know how to fix because the content size is set in the code at runtime not in storyboard at all.

Comment: It's because you are using auto layout _inside_ the scroll view in the storyboard. Content size works a different way when you do that. But that is a different question! See for example my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21719128/341994 And also my book explains it, as well as examples after the one I pointed you to.

Comment: Thanks Matt, you're the best.